# ggplot in shiny app: return a blank line

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, shiny, plotly

I am trying to add conditional trend lines to a plot. The code below works when 1 or 2 checkboxes are selected, but not when 0 checkboxes are selected. How do I return a blank or null line that still satisfies the arguments? I've tried returning `geom_blank()` and returning `NULL`.

When 0 checkboxes are selected, the code below returns the error:

```
Warning in is.na(e2) :
  is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
Warning: Error in eval: incorrect length (0), expecting: 100
```

I should add that my real app has many different checkbox groups, so adding conditionals to the actual plot creation is not feasible.

app.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

df1 <- as.data.frame(list('user'=c(rep('A',50),rep('B',50)),'x'=1:100,'y'=rnorm(100)))

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    # select a user
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput("userInput","User",
                  choices=sort(unique(df1$user)),
                  selected='A')
    ),
    # plot selected user in plotly
    mainPanel(
      plotlyOutput("mainPlot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$mainPlot <- renderPlotly({

    # filter based on selected user
    filteredForUser <- reactive({
      df1 %>%
        filter(
          user == input$userInput
        )
    })
    # add a trend line based on user
    addTrendLine <- reactive({
      if (is.null(filteredForUser())) {
        return(geom_blank())
        }
      g <- geom_smooth(data=filteredForUser(), aes(x=x,y=y), method='lm')
      return(g)
    })

    # create a plot
    g <- ggplot(data=df1, aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_line() + addTrendLine()
    ggplotly(p=g)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way to go about it since you don't want to use conditionals on the reactive inputs. In this example when none of the checkboxes are ticked, `df1 %>% filter(user == input$unserInput)` returns an error.

I simply changed the `is.null()` part of your code to check for the class of `filteredForUser`.

Output is similar to @Gopala's solution. Hopefully this works for you?

#### Server function

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$mainPlot <- renderPlotly({

    # filter based on selected user
    filteredForUser <- reactive({
      try(
      df1 %>%
        filter(
          user == input$userInput
        ), silent = T)
    })

    # add a trend line based on user
    addTrendLine <- reactive({
      if (class(filteredForUser()) == "try-error") {
        return(geom_blank())
      }else{
      g <- geom_smooth(data=filteredForUser(), aes(x=x,y=y), method='lm')
      return(g)
      }
    })

    # create a plot
    g <- ggplot(data=df1, aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_line() + addTrendLine()
    ggplotly(p=g)
  })
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks! This takes care of the problem. Unfortunately I'm having a new issue, which I'll post in a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the reactive for `filteredForUser` is not handling the null case. Also, you need to add conditionally to the `ggplot` object. Try this code instead, or some variation of it:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$mainPlot <- renderPlotly({
    # filter based on selected user
    filteredForUser <- reactive({
      if (is.null(input$userInput)) {return(df1)}
      df1 %>%
        filter(
          user == input$userInput
        )
    })
    # add a trend line based on user
    getPlot <- reactive({
      g <- ggplot(data = df1, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_line() 
      if (nrow(filteredForUser()) == nrow(df1)) {
        return(g)
      }
      g <- g + geom_smooth(data=filteredForUser(), aes(x=x, y=y), method='lm')
      return(g)
    })

    # create a plot
    g <- getPlot()
    ggplotly(p=g)
  })
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this return the same result for an empty list as well as having both users checked?

Comment: Run the code and see if it meets your need. I tried and it is behaving as you desire, I believe.

Comment: Did you actually run this? Because it doesn't compile.

Comment: You need to combine it with your UI code and the call to `shinyApp()`. It is just the server portion.

Comment: I'm aware of that. It doesn't compile.

Comment: No idea what you mean by compile. I just re-ran and shows the plot, checkboxes, and the changes as I select different things. Perhaps there is some version problem. `packageVersion('shiny') [1] ‘0.12.2’`

Comment: It produces the error "Warning: Error in filter: object 'user' not found
"

Comment: Did to include `library` dplyr`? Since `filter` was originally in your code, I had assumed you did. That call to filter is using `user`, which will of course work, but with the package you intended to use.

Comment: Oops, sorry. The issue is still, as I explained in the original post, that I can't do this using conditionals to create the plot. I'll be doing this multiple times, with multiple inputs.